# How do i remove these holes and bumps?

Tags: modeling

i don't know how or why but these strange holes and bumps just showed up on a donut i was working on.Can someone help find out how to remove them.[image]

Comment: Maybe provide your blend file…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.